# How to test if a function was called in my express controller function

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

Testing newbie, learning the ropes.

I'm trying to test my error handler controller. After a few hours, I have managed to get it working but need some feedback on the implementation.

Something feels wrong when I start changing the NODE_ENV but I'm not sure how to get around it.

I've written tests separate tests for sendErrorDev and sendErrorProd, so here I just need to test to see if they were called?

`errorController.js`:

```js
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

const handleValidationErrorDB = err => {
  const errors = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.message);

  const message = `Invalid input data. ${errors.join('. ')}`;

  return new AppError(message, 400);
};

const sendErrorDev = (err, req, res) => {
  return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    status: err.status,
    error: err,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack
  });
};

const sendErrorProd = (err, req, res) => {
  if (err.isOperational) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      status: err.status,
      message: err.message
    });
  }

  return res.status(500).json({
    status: 'error',
    message: 'Something went very wrong!'
  });
};

const handleGlobalErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    helpers.sendErrorDev(err, req, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    let error = { ...err };
    error.message = err.message;

    if (error.name === 'ValidationError')
      error = helpers.handleValidationErrorDB(error);

    helpers.sendErrorProd(error, req, res);
  }
};

const helpers = {
  sendErrorDev,
  sendErrorProd,
  handleGlobalErrors,
  handleValidationErrorDB
};

module.exports = helpers;
```

`errorController.test.js`:

```js
const { mockRequest, mockResponse } = require('../express-mocks');
const AppError = require('../../src/utils/appError');

const errorController = require('../../src/controllers/errorController');

describe('errorController', () => {
  describe('handleGlobalErrors', () => {
    let req;
    let res;
    let newError;

    beforeEach(() => {
      req = mockRequest();
      res = mockResponse();
      newError = new AppError('Some error', 500);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
    });

    it('should call sendErrorDev in development', () => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

      const spy = jest
        .spyOn(errorController, 'sendErrorDev')
        .mockImplementation(jest.fn());

      errorController.handleGlobalErrors(newError, req, res);

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      spy.mockRestore();
    });

    it('should call sendErrorProd in production', () => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

      const spy = jest
        .spyOn(errorController, 'sendErrorProd')
        .mockImplementation(jest.fn());

      errorController.handleGlobalErrors(newError, req, res);

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      spy.mockRestore();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `null` as the first parameter to `.call` which is supposed to be the object you want to invoke the function as a method of. Try removing the `.call` and just invoke it as:

```
errorController.handleGlobalErrors(newError, req, res);
```

Comment: Yeah I would agree with you seems weird but vs code defines Function.call(this: Function, thisArgs)

I've tried running errorController.handleGlobalErrors.call(newError, req, res) but then I get undefined.

The code I posted does run fine but seems messy

Comment: ah, I missed the fact that you're using `.call` - why are you doing that instead of directly invoking it?

Comment: Good point, I think it was just left in after trying a few different things.